# Loop through JavaScript object - which one is faster?

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization

between saving a key name like this

```
    for(var key in this.data)
        {
            var key_name = key;
            for(key in this.data[key_name].content){
                alert(this.data[key_name].content[key].score);
            }
        }
```

or making checkpoint objects for every parent node

```
    for(var key in this.data)
        {
            var obj = this.data[key];
            for(key in obj.content){
                var  inner_obj = obj.content;
                alert(inner_obj[key].score);
            }
        }
```

which one has better performance? any other suggestion?

Comment: Why don't you try this yourself?

Comment: http://jsperf.com/

Comment: Hey, guys, this is stackoverflow, not only a forum. It is intented to be a knowledge resource. So if you don't know, just ignore the question. That's my point of view. +1

Comment: I just want to ask  anyone who experienced this problem. Will it be better if we discuss here?

Comment: @yunzen with questions like this, there is no "know." There is only "measure."

Comment: The first rule of thumb is that if you really need to know the answer to a performance question, you have to benchmark it yourself to measure.  As others have suggested, [jsperf](http://jsperf.com) is a very useful tool for this type of thing.  The second rule of thumb is that if you are going to be dereferencing a property more than once in a loop, then it's probably wise to store the value in a local variable and use the local variable.  Local variables are the fastest type of variable access.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL If you don't want to answer, you are free to ignore. I think it is a question that has to do with how to write good code. If you think, people should write bad code: there you go. Do you know the anser? Don't you want to know the answer?

Comment: @LuangCh just an FYI: this question has nothing to do with [tag:json].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically at least, the fastest would be to get the object reference outside the inner loop. In practice the difference might not be that big, if the browser is already doing this internally. Also, the performance might differ between browsers.

```
for(var key in this.data) {
  var obj = this.data[key].content;
  for(var key2 in obj){
    alert(obj[key2].score);
  }
}
```

Note that you should use separate variables for the loops, otherwise it will be hard to follow which values is in the variable at which point when you put some actual code in the loops.

#### Edit:

When I [measure the performance](http://jsperf.com/so-question-9853395/2) in IE and Firefox, I find that this method is slightly faster than the methods proposed in the question. However, the difference is so small that you should not be concerned with it. Either method works just fine, and any performance concerns would be what you actually do with the values inside the inner loop.

Comment: Thanks @Guffa. I agree that your solution provide the best result but what about memory that require to create an object reference. Does it worth with that much memory it had to spend?

Comment: @LuangCh: A reference to an object uses the same amount of memory as a reference to string object. As it's reusing the same variable over and over it's very little memory anyway.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Only one way to know for sure: **measure it.**

http://jsperf.com/so-question-9853395

[image]

(click through for up-to-date results)

Answer (score 4):

You should use a combination of the two:

```
for(var key in this.data)
    {
        var inner_obj = this.data[key].content;
        for(ikey in inner_obj){
            alert(inner_obj[ikey].score);
        }
    }
```

This would be the fastest way to do it compared to your two proposed solutions.

Please note that I renamed `key` to `ikey` inside the inner loop to avoid confusion.

After verification, my solution is indeed the fastest:
[image: Proof of speed]
<sub>(source: [minus.com](http://i.minus.com/ibqGL9wNRtcN3i.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Why do you know this is fastest?

Comment: I assumed this to be the fastest of the proposed solutions since in his first solution there are: n assignations + n*m*3+1 lookups, in his second solution there are n + n*m assignations + n + n*m*2 lookups (hence the consistent benchmark results posted by MДΓΓ БДLL). My solution does n assignations and n+n*m lookups, which is a small improvement. It obviously does not change the time complexity (n*m) where n is the size of `this.data` and m the size of `obj.content`.

Comment: It seems to be that array lookup operation is much more (about 20 times?) expensive as object lookup

Comment: @Nepoxx downvote changed to upvote.  Thank you for giving data supporting your hypothesis!

Answer (score 0):

From an code interpreter's point of view, the first one should be faster. In the second example every loop you have to access the `this.data` array.

In modern browsers you might have a good Just In Time compiler. If this is true, this JIT could possibly 'translate' your code in the exact same opcode.

So you have to test in different browsers by executing your code several times (I mean several thousand times) and measure the execution time.

If you don't have a JIT compiler in your browser folloding would be even faster.

```
var data = this.data
for(var keyA in data)
    {
        var content = data[keyA].content;
        for(keyB in content){
            alert(content[keyB].score);
        }
    }
```